# jstl output doesn't work

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, jstl

I'm working on making an application (developed for tomcat 5.5) to be compatible with tomcat 7 (7.0.27). I'm having problems with jstl, simply tags are not output when I specify:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
```

in my WEB-INF/web.xml file (previously, the 2.4 version was used).

An example .jsp file:

```
%@page
   language="java"
   pageEncoding="utf-8"
   contentType="text/html;charset=utf-8"
   buffer="none"
%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="uri:path-to-layout/layout" prefix="layout" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<fmt:bundle basename="com.path.to.resources.Labels">
```

...

```
<td><input
name="j_username"
id="j_username" 
maxlength="30" 
accesskey="2" 
type="text"
style="width: 150px;"
value="<c:out value="${pageContext.request.remoteUser}" default="" />" /></td>
```

Instead of expected output, I receive:

```
${pageContext.request.remoteUser}
```

as the value in the text field.

I use JSTL 1.2.1, Tomcat 7.0.27, JSP 2.2. The code compiles, and when I change web-app version in web.xml from 3.0 to 2.4 it works without outputting those values directly (although there are other issues which force me to use 3.0 version). Any ideas what could be the cause of this problem?

Comment: try removing -> default="" it looks like you have that inside of the c:out tag.

Comment: @ChadNC: default is a valid attribute of c:out.

Comment: What is the result of `${pageContext.request.remoteUser}` if you directly print it using `<c:out>` tag, that is outside `<input>` tag? It is possible that the value is not stored in the variable that you are using hence it is using the default value.

Comment: In other words, JSTL works fine but EL not. To exclude the one and other, does it work when placed outside JSTL tags? E.g. `<input value="${pageContext.request.remoteUser}"/>`. What libraries exactly do you now all have in `/WEB-INF/lib`? @Logan: that returns normally the logged-in user, it's not a custom variable or something.

Comment: Hi, no it still doesn't work if I try <input value="${pageContext.request.remoteUser}"/>

Comment: I have exactly 117 files in mt /WEB-INF/lib directory (all of them are inherited from the project which worked fine on tomcat 5.5)

Comment: The files that I think could be related to this: commons-jexl-1.1.jar, jstl.jar, standard.jar, taglibs-datetime.jar, taglibs-input.jar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mentioned that you were using JSTL 1.2.1, which I assume to be the following ones which are hijacked from the Glassfish server:

- `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-1.2.1.jar`
- `javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api-1.2.1.jar`

However, as per the comments you seem to still have the old JSTL 1.0/1.1 libraries among the 117 files in the `/WEB-INF/lib`:

- `jstl.jar`
- `standard.jar`

That would only have conflicted. **Remove** them.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I tried what you said, but after that I cannot compile the project, I get: build.xml:247: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ValueExpression

Comment: The above happens when I try to built this project in eclipse. I also tried to remove those files from my tomcat's WEB-INF/lib directory and restart the server, that didn't make any difference, though.

Comment: Then your classpath is apparently more messed up with old EL libraries. The mentioned class is part of JSP/EL 2.1 which is normally already supplied by the servletcontainer itself. It would be helpful if you post a list of all those 117 JARs in `/WEB-INF/lib` anyway. Perhaps the previous developer has placed servlet-container specific libraries in there which is a [no-no](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4076706). By the way, Tomcat doesn't have a `/WEB-INF/lib` directory, but it does have a `/lib` directory and you should **absolutely not** remove any files from there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have actually managed to solve this issue. Instead of using servlet 3.0 declaration, I stuck with the 2.4 and included all the jar library from the old project. What I didn't realize was tomcat 5.5 storing .jars in several different lib folders. The solution was simply to include all of those (well, some of them had to be removed as they causes other problems) into my WEB-INF/lib folder. This seemed to be a problem. Thanks for your detailed explanation (I will up vote and and award you a bounty)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use single-quotes for the `c:out`, otherwise you're ending the `value` attribute of the `input` tag. Do this instead:

```
<td><input name="j_username" id="j_username" maxlength="30" accesskey="2"
     type="text" style="width: 150px;" 
     value="<c:out value='${pageContext.request.remoteUser}' default='' />" /></td>
```

Comment: Just tried tried, it actually doesn't make any difference to the output.

Comment: Does it work without the c:out, just using straight EL, i.e.: value="${pageContext.request.remoteUser}"

Comment: No, it doesn't make any difference to the output

Comment: While nested quotes can confuse IDEs and developers, this actually doesn't matter to the JSP compiler. The JSP compiler doesn't care about those nested quotes at all when parsing taglibs. All it sees is only the `<c:xxx ... />`. Ultimately the final result is syntactically valid.