# EL implicit objects not recognizing

Tags: jsp, tomcat, el

Setting some value in session my interceptor and I sure someValue is there is session.

```
session.setAttribute("someValue", settingSomeValueHere);

<c:out value="${sessionScope.someValue}"/> is printing like 
${sessionScope.someValue} in my JSP output.
```

but I can get the same value with 
    `<%= session.getAttribute("someValue")%>`

in my jsp, added tlds like

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tld/fmt.tld" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="/WEB-INF/tld/c.tld" %>
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tld/fn.tld" prefix="fn" %>
```

below are the jars which are in my war's lib. doubt is, Is there any unnecessary jars related to this?

using tomcat 7.0, found some log while server is up

```
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
```

[image]

Comment: are tag are present in web-info 'tld' ? better use 
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

Comment: Tried with <%@ taglib uri="java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"; prefix="c" %> too.. the same problem

Comment: Can you check the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757498/jstl-output-doesnt-work. I see that you are using jstl 1.2. What version of servlets are you using? Can you post your web.xml?

Comment: It's worked for me once I changed <web-app> declaration in web.xml from <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app> to <web-app version="2.5" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemalocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">